# Does $\frac{\langle a_k,b_k\rangle}{\|a_k\|}$ converge, if $(a_k)_k$ and $(b_k)_k$ tend to $0$ and $b\neq 0$ respectively?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

If $(a_k)_k$ and $(b_k)_k$ both convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that their limits are $0$ and $b\neq0$ respectively. Does the sequence.

$$\frac{\langle a_k,b_k \rangle}{\|a_k\|}$$ converge? (where $\langle a_k,b_k \rangle$ is the scalar product).

I'm not really sure how to go about this, since the numerator and the denominator both go to $0$( all norms are equivalent so it doesn't matter which norm we choose for the denominator).

I figured I might try using the sandwich theorem to approximate this but I'm not sure how, since the numerator is basically $a^1_kb^1_k * a^2_kb^2_k$ and if $(a_k)_k$ goes to $(0,0)$ obviously the component sequences both tend to $0$ and i can't separate them from the component sequences of $b_k$. So I'm not sure how to go about this!
Any hints at all would be appreciated
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you intend by $(a_k)_k$?  You say it is a convergent sequence in $\Bbb R^2$.  Is it a diagonalization of some sort because of the double indices?  Or is it just a sequence of points, which should just be indexed once.

Comment: I'm sorry , that's the kind of notation we use at uni, double indices.
It's just a sequence in $R$. $a_k$ would be the notation you prefer I assume, sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @RossMillikan Some people use $(a_k)_k$ in the same sense as $(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty$.

Comment: No need to feel sorry, most people use it as a short version of $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

Note we have

$\dfrac{\langle a_n, b_n \rangle}{\Vert a_n \Vert} = \langle \dfrac{a_n}{\Vert a_n \Vert }, b_n \rangle; \tag 1$

since

$\Vert \dfrac{a_n}{\Vert a_n \Vert} \Vert = \dfrac{\Vert a_n \Vert}{\Vert a_n \Vert} = 1, \tag 2$

we have

$e_n = \dfrac{a_n}{\Vert a_n \Vert} \in S^1, \tag 3$

where $S^1$ is the unit circle, is a sequence of unit vectors in $\Bbb R^2$; furthermore, for any sequence of unit vectors $e_n \in S^1$, we can find $a_n \to 0$ such that (3) binds; as a simple example, set

$a_n = \dfrac{e_n}{n}; \tag 4$

then

$a_n \to 0. \tag 5$

The question then really hinges on finding $\langle e_n, b \rangle$; but if we take

$e_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n b_n}{ \Vert b_n \Vert}, \tag 6$

which we can always do once $n$ becomes big enough, since $b_n \to b$ implies $\Vert b_n \Vert \to \Vert b \Vert \ne 0$,

we have

$\langle e_n, b \rangle =\langle \dfrac{(-1)^n b_n}{ \Vert b_n \Vert}, b \rangle = (-1)^n \langle \dfrac{b_n}{\Vert b_n \Vert}, b \rangle = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{\Vert b_n \Vert} \langle b_n, b \rangle; \tag 7$

but

$\dfrac{1}{\Vert b_n \Vert} \langle b_n, b \rangle \to \dfrac{1}{\Vert b \Vert} \langle b, b \rangle = \dfrac{\Vert b \Vert^2}{\Vert b \Vert} = \Vert b \Vert; \tag 8$

we then have

$\langle e_n, b \rangle \to \Vert b \Vert, \; n \; \text{even}, \tag 9$

and

$\langle e_n, b \rangle \to -\Vert b \Vert, \; n \; \text{odd}, \tag{10}$

so the sequece $\langle e_n, b \rangle$ fails to converge.  Thus the sequence (1) fails to converge as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Let $$a_n = \left((-1)^n\cdot\frac1n, \frac1n\right), \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{N}$$
and $b_n = (1, 1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the constant sequence $(1,1)$.

We have:

$$\frac{\langle a_n, b_n\rangle}{\|a_n\|} = \frac{(-1)^n\cdot\frac1n + \frac1n}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}} = \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

This sequence does not converge.

Comment: According to the question, $b_n \not \to 0$.